# Coulomb/Kepler potential dynamics. NDSolve breaks

Tags: differential-equations

I've been trying to do a simple dynamics in coulomb potential (electron(s) around a nucleus). My equations break down. I think it's because of a divide-by-zero error.

Is there a way to make it work?

This is what I have so far:

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
eqs = {{Derivative[1][q][T] == p[T], 
    Derivative[1][p][T] == -q[T]/(4 Pi Abs[ q[T]]^3)}, {q[0] == 2, 
    p[0] == 0.1}};
vars = {q[T], p[T]};
time = {T, 0, 20};
step = 1/25;
solee = NDSolve[eqs, vars, time, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", 
   StartingStepSize -> step, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[vars /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time], 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
Plot[Evaluate[vars /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time]]
```

I've used the documentation in `tutorial/NDSolveSPRK`.

**Update (1)**

In the second plot, you can see that the trajectories start to jump. It's an unphysical behavior. A correct solution would be periodic or pseudo-periodic orbits.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{p[T]^2/2 - 1/(4 Pi q[T]), p[T]^2/2, -(1/(4 Pi q[T]))} /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time]]
```

Plots total, kinetic and potential energy. the total energy (blue line) should be a straight horizontal line.

**Update (2)**

If I comment out `4 Pi`, I get the correct result.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
eqs = {{Derivative[1][q][T] == p[T], 
    Derivative[1][p][T] == -q[T]/(*4 Pi *) (
     Norm[q[T]]^3)}, {q[0] == {1, 0.1, 0.1}, p[0] == {0.1, 1, 0.1}}};
vars = {q[T], p[T]};
time = {T, 0, 20};
step = 0.01;
solee = NDSolve[eqs, vars, time(*, Method->"ExplicitEuler", 
   StartingStepSize->step,MaxSteps->Infinity*)];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{p[T], q[T]}} /. First[solee]], 
 Evaluate[time], PlotPoints -> 100]
Plot[Evaluate[{vars} /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time]]
Plot[Evaluate[{Norm[q[T]], q[T]} /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time]]
Plot[Evaluate[{Norm[p[T]]^2/2 - 1/(*4 Pi*) Norm[q[T]], Norm[p[T]]^2/
    2, -(1/(*4 Pi*) Norm[q[T]])} /. First[solee]], Evaluate[time]]
```

So it seems that the problem might be with initial conditions.

Comment: Works without a hitch for me.  I get two nice-looking figures. Or is the problem that they are not what you expected?

Comment: Two comments: i) the real problem is 3 dimensional; here you treat it as 1 dimensional; ii) you need to soften your force so that when particles go through each other the force does not become infinite.

Comment: @chris what do you mean by softening the force?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries at the time just before 20, the second curve starts jumping. if you increase time (for example to 200), the motion doesn't look like an orbit.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I updated the question, I couldn't find the link to the correct solution but total energy has to be conserved.

Comment: it seems looking at the code of say http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PlanarThreeBodyProblem/ should give you a good idea on what do to? or may be this http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RestrictedThreeBodyProblemInAPlane/

Comment: @chris I'm still new to mathematica. i looked at the examples, they involve a bit more writing. the second one is planar coordinates. However, looking at the first one, writing `eqs` in terms of vector (`eqs = {{Derivative[1][q][T] == p[T], 
    Derivative[1][p][T] == -q[T]/(
     4 Pi Norm[q[T]]^3)}, {q[0] == {1, 0, 0}, p[0] == {0, 0.5, 0}}};`)should've given a result but I still run into problems. again, i'm new so some things are confusing.

Comment: I would recommend using "StiffnessSwitching" as the method, and to soften the potential (as suggested by others) by just adding a small constant to the denominator: 1/(r + dr). Also, make sure you switch the sign of the force when it crosses the origin in 1D.

Comment: @Guillochon Maybe you can find time to post an answer one day :)

Answer (score 0):

The 1-d Kepler problem equals the radial Kepler problem with upwards centifugal force L^2/r^3 == omega^2 r[t] on a trajectory in a plane over head and L a constant as in any 2d or 3d rotational invariant field of force

```
r''[t]== -1/r[t]^2 +2 L^2/r[t]^3
```

which is solved by the energy trick

```
(r'[t] r''[t]  == -r'[t]/r[t]^2 + 2 L^2/r[t]^3) 
 ==( 0  ==  D[ 1/2 r'[t]^2 - D[ 1/r[t]  +  L^2/r[t]2 +C[1],t])   /;  r'[t]!=0
```

The introduction of the repelling potential L^2/r^2 makes it impossible to reach the singularity of -1/r of the gravitational potential.

Except for L=0, the radial free fall case.

With notation in differentials

```
dr/dt  == 1/(dt/dr)
```

the equation is solved for t as a function of {r->t[r]} for intervals {t,r} of monotonicity.

The replacement rules respect ArcTanh as a logarithmus, so we resort to Simplify its sqzare root argument explicitely

```
((#[[1, 1, 1]] == #[[1, 2, 1]] &)[  
    DSolve[{ r''[t] == -1/r[t]^2 }, r, t] ] /. 
          {ArcTanh[x_] :>  ArcTanh[Sqrt[Simplify[x^2]]], 
          Sqrt[x_] a_ :> Sqrt[Simplify[x a^2]]}) /. 
{C[2] :> -t0, C[1] :> 2/r0}

(ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 + r0/r[t]]] + Sqrt[ r[t]/r0 (1 + r[t]/r0)]])^2 ==  2 (t - t0)^2/r0^3
```

of the radial motion with angular momentum L = 0. Very nice, to observe Keplers 3. law of t^2/rmax^3 scaling, even here.

As obvious by every day experience, there are two solutions:

1. throw upwards, the solution is put together of the   upward until r'=0
2. and the downward solution from the maximum down to r=0

There is an old controversy about the logically indecidable question, what the point particle is doing, if with L=0 it hits the center:

1. In QM, there is never L=0, thats the answer of Dirac. Because at least L=+-1/2
2. In Schroedingers (outdated) scalar nonrelativistc  QM, the state with \vec L=0 is the statistical case of 3d-spherical constant radial waves with psr[r=0]=0, the particle hits r=0 with probability 0. The analysis is subtle and triggered the start of modern functional analysis of self adjoint operators in Hilbert spaces with real spectrum. The relativistic version is inacceptable. That fact triggered Dirac.
3. Newton: throw downwards, the stone hits the center in a finite time with
   velocity oo and performs another half period on the opposite side and back.
4. Einstein-Schwarzschild: For an observer at infinity the particle is disappearing by red shift from sight at the radius  where it aquires speed of light.
5. Newton + deformation group theory: The straight radial line segment {0,r0} is the limit of all Kepler ellipses of equal greatest diameter, all rotating at the same half period time, extrapolated to the limit of the smaller axis -> 0. The particle will be reflected at the origin and oscillates in {0,r0}.

From number 5 follows a little theorem: The Newtonian time for a free central fall, from 2r at rest to 0,  equals the full period on the circular orbits of radius r. 3. Keplers law can be  applied.

```
R = NDSolveValue[
      {r''[t] == -1/r[t] + 10^-7/r[t]^3, r[0] == 4, r'[0] == 0}, 
       r, {t, 0, 5 4^(3/2)}]

 Plot[R[t], {t, 0, 5 4^(3/2)}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Radial Free Fall]