# Lagrangian form of Earth-Sun Kepler blows up NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, physics, astronomy

I've looked at [this 1-D SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/coulomb-kepler-potential-dynamics-ndsolve-breaks). That question seems to have difficulties around diverging potential functions, and I don't have that. I've looked at [this 2-D 3-body demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PlanarThreeBodyProblem/), but that starts with equations of motion and I want to start with Lagrangians and symbolically derive the equations of motion.

The big picture is that I am developing a generalized Lagrangian solver and sanity checking it with small, standard scenarios. I got the original idea for the solver from the Wolfram blog, in [this article by Moylan](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/01/stabilized-n-link-pendulum/). My version of Moylan's solver passes his scenario and passes a damped simple harmonic oscillator, but it fails on the 2-D "reduced" Kepler problem. I don't know whether I have bugs or whether I am just using Mathematica clumsily, specifically with NDSolve.

I have checked this as much as I can visually and with cross references. For instance, the equations of motion I symbolically derive match those in [this MIT courseware document](http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/guide17.pdf).

I show all details below and will be very grateful for advice.

I only need 2-D because all 2-body Kepler problems are planar.

The "reduced" Kepler problem is a problem in two degrees of freedom, $r$ and $\theta$, concerning motion of a particle of "reduced mass" $m_{Earth}m_{Sun}/(m_{Earth}+m_{Sun})$ (again, see [MIT](http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/guide17.pdf.)).

Following [Moylan](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/01/stabilized-n-link-pendulum/), we write:

[image]

I hope you can see the reason for my interest in Moylan's method: the conciseness is valuable and worth generalizing to other problems. The Kepler problem doesn't have any non-conservative forces, but I have preserved that term in the code just for the purposes of that generalization. It works for a damped harmonic oscillator, for example.

```
coordinates = {r[τ], θ[τ]};
velocities = D[coordinates, τ];
L = 1/2 μ r'[τ]^2 + 1/2 μ r[τ]^2 θ'[τ]^2 - G M μ/r[τ];
nonConservativeForces = -{0, 0}*velocities;
equations = 
  MapThread[{q, v, h} \[Function] D[D[L, v], τ] - D[L, q] == h,
   {coordinates, velocities, nonConservativeForces}];
```

For the rest of this post, I will paste images of a Notebook. [Self-contained code is in this gist](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/180b54ca8d7dafc25806c6d80baada39) that anyone can paste into a Notebook and run.

Mathematica finds the following equations of motion, which match the MIT reference up to units and constants:

[image]

We need numerical values, which I supply with a list of substitution rules:

[image]

And sanity-check by comparing the gravitational force to the centripetal force with these constants:

[image]
[image]

Should be close enough.

I then solve the numerical equations with the following code:

[image]

The results plot as follows (please see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/180b54ca8d7dafc25806c6d80baada39) for the lengthy but uninformative plotting code):

[image]

OK, pretty much nothing is right. I expected $r(\tau)$ to be more-or-less constant, but it blows up. I expected $\theta(\tau)$ to be more-or-less linearly increasing, but it's not linear. Angular momentum and energy are not even slightly conserved.

I hope this is just something dumb on my part, but I don't see it. Anyone spot a problem that's easy to fix? Or have I waded into deeper waters?

**EDIT**: just realized that my numerical value for `day` is off by a factor of 365.25 (oops)  changing it does NOT solve the bigger problem, though. The angular momentum and energy are still not conserved.  I updated [the public gist](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/180b54ca8d7dafc25806c6d80baada39).

Comment: It would help, if instead of screenshots of code, there would be *code*...

Comment: @gwr code is in this gist https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/180b54ca8d7dafc25806c6d80baada39, as stated in the body of the question :)

Comment: @J. M. I'm curious about the source of the Greek symbols in your (fine) edit. Did you just paste in Unicode symbols manually, or is there an automated method of copy-paste from Mathematica?

Comment: Personally, I know the codepoints and enter them directly. ;) Other people either use [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043) or type in the $\LaTeX$ version (e.g. `$\tau\mu$`), and then directly copy the output of MathJax.

Comment: The [M.SE editor toolbar buttons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) that J.M. linked to in his comment are very handy.

Comment: @gwr see comments and edits by J.M. concerning Greek symbols in pasted code; I learned something about how to improve future posts by pasting actual code instead of screen shots. Research also uncovered this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183045/how-can-i-type-unicode-characters-without-using-the-mouse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember in your action to subtract your potential energy from the kinetic energy ${\cal L}= T- V$.

Forget the angular stuff for a second.  You want $\partial_t (M r') = - G M/r^2$.
This isn't the equation of motion you were getting -- see the glitch? You had set up a repulsive system instead of an attractive one.

The potential (you want) is attractive, so your ${\cal L}$ **should** be:

```
 L = 1/2 μ (r'[τ]^2 + r[τ]^2 θ'[τ]^2) + G M μ/r[τ];
```

The sign in front of $G M /r$ is switched relative to yours.

This allows your integration to proceed merrily, and in the period of one year, you can plot your orbit:

```
ParametricPlot[{r[τ] Cos[θ[τ]], r[τ] Sin[θ[τ]]} /. soln[[1]] /.
               τ -> t // Evaluate, {t, 0, tlim}]
```

yielding:

[image: orbit]

Here's the entire output of your approach applied to a year with the attractive action (and notice the correct equation of motion in `r`):

[image: output]

Comment: Excellent catch! Energy conservation is still fluctuating in the fifth decimal place, but $r$ and $theta$ are behaving as expected. Much obliged.

Comment: From looking at L, it may be that there are numerical problems.

Comment: @John Joseph M. Carrasco --- energy conservation demonstrated by removing erronious division by degree symbol and changing the sign in the potential-energy term. Your eyes on this much appreciated: another instances of Linus's Law at work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_Law

Comment: For physical systems like this, one would usually want to switch to a Hamiltonian formulation, which would then allow you to use the [`"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"` method of `NDSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html).

Comment: Few quick comments: a) I always find it easier to work and debug in units close to one [ in this case: {AU, years, SolarMass, radians}].  This way you don't have to worry so much about noise from large cancellations. Not a real prob here, but good practice. (Can always convert to PlanckUnits if want large exponents later)  b) might as well throw in a check for conserved quantities and analytic partial solns -- easy to see here EoM indep of 1 of your vars -- only it's derivative (conservation of ang. momenta).  c) define Kin and Pot separately and combine them as necessary for L, H etc.

Comment: @J.M. I wrote a few examples (damped harmonic oscillator, spring-and-dashpot trusses, rigid bodies in free-fall and under constant acceleration) in both Lagrangian and Hamiltonian form and fed them through NDSolve and experimented with the options you suggested and with others. I compared the two forms for conserved quantities as suggested by Carrasco. The Hamiltonian form conserves momenta analytically, and tends to produce better and more stable results overall. I'm considering writing an automatic converter from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Reb, correct; SPRK methods are specifically designed to keep numerical errors in the Hamiltonian bounded even over a long integration interval (unlike RK and multistep methods), so it is indeed profitable to formulate a physical system in Hamiltonian form whenever you can. [Hairer/Nørsett/Wanner](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=F93u7VcSRyYC&pg=PA312) has a good discussion on *symplectic* methods. (And, indeed, as John says, correct unit scaling is paramount for accurate integrations.)